# Вывод в Java println без System.out

Tags: java

Как и что нужно импортировать что-бы в коде просто писать println("..."); без System.out. ?
У этих двух способов есть свои плюсы и минусы. Какие они?

- System.out.println("....");
- println("....");

[image: java]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

и сможешь выводить в консоль коммандой
`out.println("");`

плюсы и минусы... меньше писанины. пакет java.lang импортируеться автоматически, а без импорта пришлось бы тебе для вывода писать  `java.lang.System.out.println("");`
если тебе лень для вывода печатать `sout+tab`  -  создай свой метод c коротким именем `p` и вызывай его.

```
public static void p(String txt){ 
    System.out.println(txt);
}
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

       p("text");

}
```

если надо кроме строк печатать

```
public static void p(Object ob){
    System.out.println(ob);
```

Comment: Как вывести без out.  print("");

Comment: @theblackmonkey подлючением сторонней библиотеки mindview, эта та, которая import static .....     public static void print(Object ob){
    System.out.println(ob);  вынеси за метод мейн и будет тебе печатать без System.out

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/137558/

Comment: @theblackmonkey получилось разобраться?